# Laravel Query CASE with WHEREBETWEEN

Tags: sql, laravel

I have the following query:

```
    $ordersAllProducts=Product::groupBy('products.SKU')
        ->selectRaw('products.SKU,
        (CASE
        WHEN sum(orders.quantity)>1 THEN sum(orders.quantity)
        ELSE 0
        END) as quantity_sum')
        ->leftjoin('orders','products.SKU','=','orders.SKU')
        ->get();
```

It all works great, but I need to return the sum of orders.quantity between certain dates.

I've tried this code:

```
$ordersAllProducts=Product::groupBy('products.SKU')
            ->selectRaw('products.SKU,
            (CASE
            WHEN sum(orders.quantity)>1 THEN sum(orders.quantity)
            ELSE 0
            END) as quantity_sum')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$from, $toTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
            ->leftjoin('orders','products.SKU','=','orders.SKU')
            ->get();
```

It works great but all of a sudden, not all of the fields from products (left table) are joined, i.e.

Before Between Dates (showing sum of quantity for all dates):

```
+-----+--------+
|SKU  |Quantity|
|ABC  | 10     |
|DEF  | 20     |
|XYZ  | 40     |
+-----+--------+
```

After Between Dates (now DEF has no orders between the dates)

```
+-----+--------+
|SKU  |Quantity|
|ABC  | 8      |
|XYZ  | 14     |
+-----+--------+
```

My desired output is below (showing 0 for DEF)

```
+-----+--------+
|SKU  |Quantity|
|ABC  | 8      |
|DEF  | 0      |
|XYZ  | 14     |
+-----+--------+
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your where condition that filters dates could be filtering the empty results from the join i.e. when `DEF` is 0.

You may consider filtering in the join on the orders table eg

```php
$ordersAllProducts=Product::groupBy('products.SKU')
                          ->selectRaw('products.SKU,
                                      (CASE
                                           WHEN sum(orders.quantity)>1 THEN sum(orders.quantity)
                                           ELSE 0
                                       END) as quantity_sum')
                 
                          ->leftjoin('orders',function($ordersJoin) use($from,$toTime){
                              $ordersJoin->on('products.SKU','=','orders.SKU');
                              $ordersJoin->whereBetween('date', [$from, $toTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                          })
                        ->get();
```

Let me know if this works for you.